# amazon cloud high request usage on 1st time account creation

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i created aws acc for my aws tutorials and select the free trial. i deployed 2 jar files to test. ntg big, just to-do app, a minimal code just to test if it works for my tutorials. n 2 days later i received an alert which i set up to trigger 1% of $1. heres the breakdown:

[image]

i am aware that i have to stop terminate the application when im done with tutorial for the day, but what im curious why the request is so high in 2 days?

Comment: You haven't specified what exactly did you deploy? What resources did you create?

Comment: @Marcin https://github.com/in28minutes/deploy-spring-boot-aws-eb.git - i deployed 1 jar each time, not more than 1.